# hive-jdbc JDBC Escape Syntax

Tags: jdbc, hive, hiveql

I have hive table:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (
   a string,
   b double,
   enumerator bigint
) PARTITIONED BY (
   asof_date date
)
```

when I try to query it using hive-jdbc, 
the select generated is:

```
  select * from FOO where asof_date = {ts '2015-05-15 00:00:00'}
```

Hive failed with error:

```
 ParseException line 1:36 cannot recognize input near '{' 'ts' ''2015-05-15 00:00:00'' in expression
```

how I can fix this?

Comment: Note: This isn't a 'sql escape', it's a JDBC escape. It sounds like Hive-jdbc doesn't support JDBC escapes (which is technically a violation of the JDBC specification). You will need to use Hive specific syntax to do this (if it exists).

Comment: The Apache JDBC driver is _very_ lame indeed -- use the Cloudera driver (based on Simba SDK) whenever you can.

Answer (score 0):

In the older versions of Hive there was no proper DATE or TIMESTAMP types, or rather, they were always stored as a String in ODBC format.

In other words `where asof_date = '2015-05-15'` should work just fine.

Or in formal SQL syntax `= date'2015-05-15'`.
Or more verbosely `= cast('2015-05-15' as DATE)`